# Is it possible to install a Microsoft Store app machine wide?

Tags: uwp, windows-installer, manifest, appx

We have a need to install our Microsoft Store app machine wide for all current and future users.
Is this possible in any way, either through the app manifest or some other setting?
Does Microsoft store offer any MSI capabilities?

Comment: I believe this is more relavant question for [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), maybe also check [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_store/windows-store-app-availability-to-all-users-of-a/e7df5ed6-7c36-447c-a43c-b58d619a23bd?auth=1)

Comment: @Ruli I will take a look, thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download the package from the store and [provision it to all the users](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/per-machine-msix.html), using the MSFT APIs.

More details:

- [Preinstalling packaged apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/deploy-preinstalled-apps)
- Deployment of an [MSIX per-machine using SCCM](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/per-machine-deployment-msix-sccm.html)
- [Download MSIX from MS Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-store/distribute-offline-apps)